# Proguard with Ant: Filtering specific jar files from a folder

Tags: ant, proguard

I can't seem to find the proper syntax for Proguard to filter out a list of jar files based on their names from a folder.

I have a folder project/lib/ that has a mix of third-party and proprietary jars.  I am specifying the proprietary jars in that folder as input jars to proguard, as well as the main program jar file in the project/ folder.

I would like to tell proguard to look in project/lib/ for library jars and filter out the previously specified proprietary jars.

From the Proguard usage [page](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/examples.html#filtering), I am lead to believe that the syntax for this is:

```
-injars project/main_jar.jar
-injars project/lib/proprietary_jar_1.jar(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)
-injars project/lib/proprietary_jar_2.jar(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)

-libraryjars project/lib/(!proprietary_jar_1.jar;,!proprietary_jar_2.jar;)
```

However, the above gives me the error:

```
Expecting separating ',' or ';', or closing ')' before ';' in argument number 1
```

How should I specify for Proguard to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProGuard manual > Usage > [Class paths](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#classpath)

The subsequent zip/ear/war/jar/file filter lists are separated by semi-colons. The individual entries in those list are separated by commas. In this case:

```
-injars project/main_jar.jar
-injars project/lib(proprietary_jar_1.jar,proprietary_jar_2.jar;!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)

-libraryjars project/lib(!proprietary_jar_1.jar,!proprietary_jar_2.jar;)
```